# 3D Objects appearing as flat in three.js

Tags: three.js

I just setup a very basic "hello world" for three.js…
But apparently my 3d cube is appearing as a 2d square…

The **code** to the js file is [here](https://github.com/Navarjun/threejs-test/blob/master/assets/scripts/main.js)

```
const t = THREE;
const scene = new t.Scene();
const camera = new t.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new t.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// create a shape
const geometry = new t.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);

// create a material
const material = new t.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFFFFFF, wireframe: true});
const cube = new t.Mesh(geometry, material);
// cube.position.y = 1;
scene.add(cube);

// camera.position.x = 300;
camera.position.z = 5;

// logic
const update = function () {
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
};

// draw scene
const render = function () {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

// run render loop (update-render-repeat)
const RenderLoop = function () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(RenderLoop);
    update();
    render();
};

RenderLoop();
```

And the **result** of the code is [here](https://navarjun.github.io/threejs-test/index.html)

[image: Imgur]

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
Sorry for not including the code

Comment: If you want strangers to spend their free time helping you, you should take the time to make an [mcve] or at least include some of your relevant code here. Asking answerers to go through your github repo isn't terribly respectful of their time.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here… trying to learn the conventions of this community.

Comment: If you haven't check out [ask] and the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building your `PerspectiveCamera` wrong:

Your way:

```
PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
```

Correct way:

```
PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
```

You need to pass the ratio `w/h`, not two separate `w, h` arguments.